# android xml scrollview showing scroll bar even without any element ... WHY?

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, layout, scrollview

I am using a scroll view in Xml file in my android project. User have to drag and drop elements in it at runtime. 
Initially it has zero element. I have adjusted its height so that it shows 2 elements at a time.

Now what I want is that when its element count is 0,1,2; it should not show any scroll bar, scroll bar should appear only when the number of elements exceeds 2.

How can I do that ?

Comment: post your layout file. I think you have mistake in layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to adjust your scrollview automatically with your layout items.

```
<ScrollView

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    Use your contents here
   </LinearLayout>
```